# URLConnection class java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Tags: java, networking

I am programming on a system with client running Java Applet on one end and server on the other. Now I have the client and server on the same computer. But as a client, I cannot see the applet and I get error like below:

```
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at MainJApplet.init(MainJApplet.java:58)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at RequestServer.sendRequest(RequestServer.java:25)
    at createGUI.createEditingBar(createGUI.java:1313)
    at GUI.createAndShowGUI(GUI.java:813)
    at MainJApplet.init(MainJApplet.java:137)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at createGUI.createEditingBar(createGUI.java:1315)
    at GUI.createAndShowGUI(GUI.java:813)
    at MainJApplet.init(MainJApplet.java:137)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Below is where the problem traced back:

```
URL url = new URL(ipAddr);
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

connection.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream()); // exception happens
```

I checked http://localhost:8080/ and port conflict. I have turn off windows firewall and yet the problem exists. Can someone kindly point me some direction? Any advice would be great! Thanks ahead!

I apologize for the long code. The first is for client.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MainJApplet extends JApplet {

    GUI gui = new GUI();
    Thread renewThread;

    public void init() {
        //pass parameters from url to applet
        String filePath = this.getParameter("FilePath");
        //temporary solution to bypass the new extention
        String userName = this.getParameter("UserName");
        String ipAddr = this.getParameter("IpAddress");
        String userLevel = this.getParameter("UserLevel");
        String ticket = this.getParameter("Ticket");
        String accessMode = this.getParameter("AccessMode"); //1-normal 2-shared 3-email

        //sharedTo will be get from the file path infor
        String sharedTo = this.getParameter("ShareTo");
        String type = this.getParameter("Type");

        gui.shareTo = sharedTo;
        gui.ticket = ticket; //this gui.ticket is used to varify email access, will be replaced

        String relativePath = "";
        try {
            //connect to servlet

            URL url = new URL(ipAddr);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
            //Passing NAME+FILE+TICKET+TYPE to server at the initialization stage
            out.write("IN");
            out.write(userName + "#");
            out.write(filePath + "#");
            out.write(ticket + "#");
            out.write(type + "#");
            out.close();

            //Wait for server response
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                    connection.getInputStream()));

            String dcodedStr;
            StringBuffer decodedStringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
            while ((dcodedStr = in.readLine()) != null) {
                decodedStringBuffer.append(dcodedStr);
            }

            String dStr = decodedStringBuffer.toString();
            in.close();

            if (dStr.equals("NOT_AUTHORIZED")) { //not passing authentication check
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(),
                        "Access Denied",
                        "Warning!",
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                return;
            } else {//pass authentication check
                String[] initResp = dStr.split("#");
                gui.FID = initResp[0]; //file ID
                gui.EditMode = Boolean.parseBoolean(initResp[1]);
                gui.userLevel = 1; //temporary set all as normal user
                boolean firstOpen = Boolean.parseBoolean(initResp[2]);
                relativePath = initResp[3];
                if (initResp[4].trim().equals("normal")) {//owner
                    gui.accessMode = 1;
                } else {//shared user
                    gui.accessMode = 2;
                }
            }
        }catch(UnknownServiceException exp){
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

    public void destroy() {
        gui.check_upon_window_close();

        if (gui.is_new_drawing == 0) {
            //2010.9.29 workDir -> FID
            if (gui.EditMode) {
                RequestServer.canClose(gui.IpAddress, gui.user, gui.FID);
            } else {
                RequestServer.canCloseNoEdit(gui.IpAddress, gui.user, gui.FID);
            }
        }
        renewThread.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd begin by checking the network connectivity to the server.

Comment: Please post the code that produces this exception.  Also, post ServerSocket binding code.

Comment: @Hippo. OP says client and server are running on the same host.

Comment: as stupid as it sounds: what's the value of `ipAddr` at runtime?

Comment: @AlexanderPogrebnyak: There could still be issues on the same machine - is the server really up? Is the client correctly connecting to localhost and the correct port?

Comment: Thank you for quick response. I am still green in the field and please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Are you running your local server on the same port as the deployed server? Also, where does the Applet get the connection info from? I agree with @AlexanderPogrebnyak, post both your server socket binding and client connection code.

Comment: Hi Hippo, do you mean to ping the ip address? Because I have the client and server on the same computer, so it's likely to always be able to connect. And "telnet" cannot be recognized in windows system.... Any other suggestions? Or am I doing in the wrong way?

Comment: Hi Matten, the ipAddr is actually the local host's ip address

Comment: Hi Hippo and AlexanderPogrebnyak, could you kindly provide me some ways to identify whether the server is up and if the client is connecting correctly? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Perception, yes, I am running both on the same port. The applet gets the connection info from my input.

Comment: @Veronica - not sure what you mean by your last comment, but Applet gets it's parameters from the web page it's included on. Please check that web page for the exact value of 'ipAddr' and copy that value to your question.

Comment: Hi Perception, the ipAddr is http://172.22.138.195:8080/ which is also my local host ip address.

Comment: Ok great, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Based off your comments my guess is that your server is binding to the loopback address (127.0.0.1, aka localhost). You didn't post what the server software is, but change it's configuration so that it binds on 0.0.0.0 instead. That should fix your issue.

Comment: Sorry. Because the server is already a packed, distributed one. I myself does not have the original code. All I know is some configuration to run the server on my own computer. I am a little bit blur here. May I know how to re-configure the binding?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I would definitely check as you mentioned once I have digested what you said. Happy new year~